# What is the significance of the number 7 in Leviticus 25:1 - 25:9?

Tags: leviticus

Leviticus 25:4-9 Shemittah Seven Years

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to the site. Could you clarify your question? As it stands right now it will probably get closed because it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: If you quote the verses in question, that would help. Also, to point out that they speak of "a seventh year" [Hebrew shebii]; and "seven sabbaths of years" [Hebrew shibah]; and the seventh month [Hebrew shebii]. Then you could explain what you mean by "shemittah".

Comment: Shemittah is the Sabbatical year, when fields are left fallow.

Comment: @Michael, explanations should go into the permanent question itself, not in ephemeral comments.

Comment: @Michael. As it stands now "*Leviticus 25:4-9 Shemittah Seven Years*" is the entire question, and it's not even a sentence, much less a question. Expecting the readers to guess or figure out what the question is supposed to mean is not a good way to get answers. Compare your brief cryptic question with some of the questions on this site that have received significant up-votes and you'll see quite a contrast.

Answer (score 1):

***In the Bible, the number seven symbolises perfection.***

> God saw all that he had made, and it was very good.  And there was evening, and there was morning – the sixth day (Genesis 1:31)

***There was no imperfection in what God had made.***

> By the seventh day God had finished the work he had been doing; so on the seventh day he rested from all his work.  And God blessed the seventh day and made it holy, because on it he rested from all the work of creating that he had done (Genesis 2:2-3).

***The Sabbath year takes place every seventh year, and God’s people were told to give the land a rest.***

> But in the seventh year the land is to have a Sabbath of rest, a Sabbath to the Lord (Leviticus 25:4).

***Likewise, after a period of forty-nine years (seven times seven), there was to be a Jubilee Year, starting on the tenth day of the seventh month, on the Day of Atonement.***

> Consecrate the fiftieth year and proclaim liberty throughout the land to all its inhabitants... The fiftieth year shall be a jubilee for you; (Leviticus 25:9-11).

***According to the Jewish calendar, we are currently in a Sabbath Year (Shemitah), due to end on September 25, 2022:***

> As soon as the Jews settled in the Holy Land, they began to count and observe seven-year cycles. Every cycle would culminate in a Sabbatical year, known as Shemitah, literally: “to release.”  The year following the destruction of the second Holy Temple was the first year of a seven-year Sabbatical cycle. In the Jewish calendar, counting from Creation, this was the year 3829, 68–69 CE on the secular calendar. By counting sevens from then, we see that the next Shemitah year will be the year 5782 after Creation, which runs from September 7, 2021 - September 25, 2022.
> https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/562077/jewish/What-Is-Shemitah.htm

The following link gives further information on the Jubilee, which is also a Shabbat of the land, and is called ‘Yovel’ in Hebrew.  This is the origin of the Latin term ‘Jubilee’ which also means 50: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmita#:~:text=The%20sabbath%20year%20(shmita%3B%20Hebrew,and%20is%20observed%20in%20Judaism.

***The biblical significance of the number seven in Leviticus chapter 25 is that God has designated seven as holy, a day of rest.  This applies also to years and to the Jubilee which is to be kept after seven times seven years have elapsed.***

Comment: That's very helpful, Lesley.  Thank you.